# Incorrect local font path when using relative url in Vue CLI 3 config

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I have a requirement to set up relative urls on a Vue application as the app can be deployed into a variety of settings.

I'm currently using Vue Cli 3.0.0-beta.6 and have modified the `vue.config.js` file so that the production environment uses relative paths.

```
// vue.config.js    
module.exports = {
  lintOnSave: false,
  configureWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      return {
        output: {
          publicPath: ''
        }
      }
    } else {
      return {
        output: {
          publicPath: '/'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However when I make a production build using `vue-cli-service build` the font path gets changed (by webpack I'm guessing) and instead of being:

`http://127.0.0.1:8080/fonts/my-font.ttf`

it gets routed through the CSS folder

`http://127.0.0.1:8080/css/fonts/my-font.ttf`

My current thinking is that I need to overwrite the webpack config that handles fonts when building prod but I'm:

- Not sure whether this is the right approach
- Not sure how to even do that
- Fed up of webpack

Any help would be awesome

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and its driving me crazy, please let us know if you found a solution.

Comment: @simon - I don't think it's possible. I think webpack screws up the relative url. I've hardcoded the production url into the publicPath for now but as soon as I have to deploy into a new location I'm going to have the same issues

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do this in `vue.config.js`:

```
chainWebpack: config => {
  config.module.loader('fonts').tap(options => {
    options.name = `../fonts/[name].[hash:8].[ext]`
  }
}
```

But generally, relative paths are problematic in SPAs, at least. if you intend to use vue-router with history mode, for example, your app will break on page refreshs.

So my best advice is to build fresh with an absolute path for each deployment.

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you set `baseUrl: ''`. The vue cli docs also recommends not to modify the `output.publicPath`.

The only downside to this is that the css and js files will be stored in the root dist directory instead of its respective css/ and js/ directories. But it should not be a problem and you may access the `index.html` file directly in the browser with all the assets having the correct paths.

For reference, [see the config docs for the baseUrl](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl).